# CSS background-image url not shown in browser, but shown in design view

Tags: codeigniter, dreamweaver

I am just getting started with dreamweaver and i get this weird problem(i use **codeigniter** framework) :

I put this code in one of my CSS selector (the url is auto-generated by dreamweaver's **browse** feature) :

```
background-image: url(../images/main.jpg);
```

This image is shown perfectly in the design view(dreamweaver) BUT its NOT shown in the real browser (i use the latest Google Chrome).

I have tried to manually browse the image with this code :

```
background-image: url(http://localhost/ci_latihan_dreamweaver/images/main.jpg);
```

But the result is same.

What should i do?Thanks :D

Comment: You must setup a webserver for this to work, browsing to `localhost` won't do you anygood if you haven't setup a webserver and the `ci_latihan_dreamweaver` directory is inside your webroot.

Comment: Where do you keep your css file? folder path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We simply have to press **f12** in Dreamweaver(run site from Dreamweaver). The Dreamweaver will generate a link that dont use the `localhost`, and the images and css works perfectly :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this one it will work

```
          background-image: url(../../images/main.jpg);
```